# I show the user's email on my web page but when I pull this page on mobile, it sometimes shows sometimes not

Tags: php, html

I have a page where the user's email would be shown. When I log onto the page on PCs, it always works, but on my mobile, sometimes the email is shown sometimes it is not.

Please see below as my code.

I have installed a plugin where I can write php in html environment.

```
<h5>Please confirm your email address, and the results will display shortly</h5>
<input name="email" required="" type="radio" value="<?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_email;
?>" /><?php global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
echo "  " . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
?>
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if you plan on add more inputs on your form later on. But I'd recommend a responsive design to make sure that it will look good on all devices.

You can use a stylesheet or create one of your own.
This link has some examples: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp